# Change behavior of input type time in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How do you change the behaviour of the input type=time in order to change the minutes before the hours in chrome and opera using the provided arrows. (the problem isn't present in firefox or edge as the user interface doesn't provide the same controls)

I'm using Angular 9 if it helps

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="time" min="0" step="1800">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I don’t think that is actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can desactivate the arrows

```
input[type='time']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
```

or you can build your own time input

Comment: I removed it to avoid user confusion, I wanted to avoid to do my own component. Thanks for the reply